# How to pass argument to method in EventTrigger from script C# Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, eventtrigger

[image: EndDrag]

Hi,
I have problem with event triggers. I don't know how can I pass an argument to my function. I need to do it through editor, because I have a lot of objects that use this script and this method is only difference between them.

It is fragment of my code, simplify for question:

```
public override void OnEndDrag(PointerEventData data)
{
    lpbc = null;
    if (data.pointerCurrentRaycast.gameObject == null || data.pointerCurrentRaycast.gameObject.tag!="Field")
    {
        return;
    }
    if (data.pointerCurrentRaycast.gameObject.tag == "Field")
    {
       //some methods to define my go
       GameObject go;
       //HERE I want to call function from picture BUT with my go
        //when I do below line, I can call EndDrag with my function, but how to pass my argument??????????
        base.OnEndDrag(data);

    }
}
```

Comment: What component are you trying to get/set? I would suggest adding a variable that defines this gameobject when it's created and query that inside the ```OnEndDrag``` trigger

Comment: Could you show any example? I try to get into GameObject (empty on screen).

Comment: What is it you are trying to achieve? i.e. in `base.OnEndDrag`, what are you trying to do with `go`? There may be a better way to achieve your goal